# Change a canvas js variable by animating it

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, canvas

Original canvas created by Jack Rugile.

I am trying to change several variables in the canvas js file on hover using a jquery function. Several work but I would like to change the radius of the glowing rotation by animating it rather than having it instantly change. Similar to the way [this](https://24.media.tumblr.com/58b6e67d546d14360f9e64aec40bc286/tumblr_mygwnsbsvF1sso6sco1_500.gif) expands.

I tried using a $timeout but i don't think that is the proper way to go.
Any suggestions?

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/3u8ukorv/)

The jquery hover is at the bottom of the js.

```
$('.containAnimation').hover(function() {
  circle.speed = 8;
  circle.thickness = 20;
  particleMax = 200;
  $timeout(function() {
    circle.radius = 150;
  }, 3000);
}, function() {
  circle.speed = 1.5;
  circle.thickness = 15;
  particleMax = 100;
  $timeout(function() {
    circle.radius = 100;
  }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: Are you using AngularJS? `$timeout` is used in AngularJS only as far as I know.

Comment: no. I just changed it to setTimeout and it delays it fine. However i'm looking for a way to make it animate instead of delay.

Comment: This render something else, but the mechanism would be the same, maybe useful as a start: http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/bS58y/

Comment: I understand how that example works, but my knowledge of canvas is basically null and don't know how I would create my version of the pixelate function in that example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Use `requestAnimationFrame` to animate by recursively calling the function.

```
$('.containAnimation').hover(function() {
  circle.speed = 8;
  circle.thickness = 20;
  particleMax = 200;
  setTimeout(animateHoverIn, 10);
}, function() {
  circle.speed = 1.5;
  circle.thickness = 15;
  particleMax = 100;
  setTimeout(animateHoverOut, 10);
});

function animateHoverIn(){
    if (circle.radius>=150){
       return;
    }
    circle.radius++;
    requestAnimationFrame(animateHoverIn);
}

function animateHoverOut(){
    if (circle.radius<=100){
       return;
    }
    circle.radius--;
    requestAnimationFrame(animateHoverOut);
}
```

Comment: EDIT: Nvm, I copied it wrong... Hi, thanks for your answer, could you put together a working demo? With your current code the entire hover function breaks and hovering changes nothing.

Comment: You just marked it as correct. What happened? Did it work?

Comment: Yes I copied it wrong I missed the first line haha. Thanks so much for this.

Comment: Why the `setTimeout(` in initial calling of `animateHoverXX` ?

Comment: The OP had it by default. I just kept it with a very low delay.